# Unkown reason for TypeError for lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def player_move(Player, board):
    playerMarker = None
    print("Player ",Player," it is your turn!")
    playerChoice = input("Please input your move: ")
    if Player == 1:
        playerMarker == 9
    else:
        playerMarker == 10
    board[playerChoice] == playerMarker
```

This produces the TypeError:

```
line 36, in player_move
board[playerChoice] == playerMarker
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Why is this, and how could I stop this from occouring? I understand str cannot be added to this list, but aren't I attempting to add integers?

Comment: Value returned by `input()` is of `str` type. You need to typecast it to `int` in order to convert it into valid index. Also, string should hold the valid integer value

Answer (score 1):

There's two problems: You're assuming `playerChoice` is an integer (it's a string and has to be converted using `int()`.*), and you're using `==` for assignment. Here's it fixed:

```
def player_move(Player, board):
    playerMarker = None
    print("Player ",Player," it is your turn!")
    # should probably check for invalid inputs here
    playerChoice = int(input("Please input your move: "))
    if Player == 1:
        playerMarker = 9
    else:
        playerMarker = 10
    board[playerChoice] = playerMarker
```

* You might be confused having come from Python 2, where `input` indeed (occasionally) returns an integer; Python 3's `input` ≙ Python 2's `raw_input`.

Comment: There is nothing like *occasionally* for the interpreter. It has set of pre-defined rules. It returns `int` only when the value entered can be type-cast to `int`

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri On the _occasion_ that the user enters something that can be type-cast to `int`, it returns `int`.

Comment: So says my comment. I think you should remove occasionally from the answer and mention the proper reason